# How to make a developed perl package with a python wrapper callable from everywhere

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, shell, perl

**A bit of context**:

I have a Perl parser, named `parse_log.pl`, that parses logs into a `.m` file (MATLAB function). In the `.m` file, the logs are stored into a MATLAB struct which is the output of the function. This function can then be called from MATLAB so the struct (logs) becomes available in the command window.

The Perl parser uses two packages, `LogAParser.pm` and `LogBParser.pm` which I put into a directory `LogParserPackage` and the main log parser function, `parse_log.pl`  uses the subs in these packages based on the command line arguments to parse a specific log.

In order to save the logs (struct) into a ‘mat’ file, I developed a Python wrapper for this Perl parser in which I use `matlab.engine` in order to save the `mat` file as a `mat v7.3` file and benefit from its compression capability.

**Questions**:

1. How to make this python/Perl module callable from everwhere in the shell (something like setup).
2. In the Python wrapper, how to check if the `matlab.engine` is installed on the user’s machine? Same question for Perl? And in case if they are not installed, how throw an exception with an informative message?

Comment: Can you add a minimal example of the perl and python scripts? See [mcve] for more information